# How CUDA kernel work on multiple blocks each of which have different time consumption?

Tags: cuda

Assume that we run a kernel function with 4 blocks {b1, b2, b3, b3}. Each the blocks requires {10, 2, 3, 4} amount of time to complete job. And our GPU could process only 2 blocks in parallel.

If then, which one is correct way how our GPU work?

[image]

Comment: The scheduling of blocks is unspecified

Comment: 1) would be typical. As it is the same kernel, there should be enough resources, as `Block 2` finished. It gets more interesting, if you add streams with multiple kernels, asynchronous memory copies, dependency graphs or the partitioning of recent datacenter GPUs. You can also have dynamic parallelism with kernels starting other kernels from device code.

Comment: I think (2) is very improbable, but it could happen that `Block2`, `Block3` and `Block4` are scheduled before `Block1` leading to an work imbalance. If you know in advance what part of the work is going to take much more time, you can circumvent the imbalance by scheduling the "long work" in its own kernel launch on a high priority stream while the "short work" is scheduled on a low priority stream.

Comment: Or you could use global atomics once in the beginning of a block to decide, what works that specific block should do depending on which block got scheduled first instead of relying on the blockIdx.

Answer (score 1):

To quote [this document](https://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3466-Programming-Guidelines-GPU-Architecture.pdf) from Nvidia:

> Threadblocks are assigned to SMs
>
> - Assignment happens only if an SM has **sufficient resources** for the entire threadblock
>
>   - Resources: registers, SMEM, warp slots
>   - Threadblocks that haven’t been assigned **wait for resources to free up**
> - **The order in which threadblocks are assigned is not defined**
>
>   - Can and does **vary between architectures**

Thus, without more information, the two scheduling are theoretically possible. In practice, this is even more complex since there are many SMs on a GPU and AFAIK each SM can now execute multiple blocks concurrently.